Role cannot access AWS Secrets Manager secret
I am baffled.
I have a secret, with the ARN
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:022528294191:secret:prjdevrdsauroraSecretD01269-itTuR5vpdyr5-ddd11d (all IDs have been changed to protect the innocent.)
I have a role prj-dev-prjdevlambdaroleEFBCDBFF-OwcoRUhPiEZI with the attached policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:022528294191:secret:prjdevrdsauroraSecretD01269-itTuR5vpdyr5-ddd11d",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}

I can assume that role with aws sts assume-role from the command-line and I copy the credential to aws configure set commands.
When I do
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:022528294191:secret:prjdevrdsauroraSecretD01269-itTuR5vpdyr5-ddd11d

I get
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation:
 User: arn:aws:sts::022528294191:assumed-role/prj-dev-prjdevlambdaroleEFBCDBFF-OwcoRUhPiEZI/testSession 
is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:022528294191:secret:prjdevrdsauroraSecretD01269-itTuR5vpdyr5-ddd11d 
because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action

I don’t understand: there patently is an identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action!

there does not seem to be any restrictive policies on the secret
the role and the permissions were all generated by CDK, so I doubt it is a simple typo
there are no Permission Boundaries
all this is within one account
other entities assuming that role have the same problem.  It’s something about the relationship between the role and the secret.

EDIT:
The secret was created by  new ServerlessCluster in the aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds library; the role, by new Role from aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam,  and the policy was created by calling the grantRead() method on the secret-object.
EDIT (and it gets weird):
I did something I should have done earlier: I created another secret, entirely by hand.  The role could not read that secret either, even after I added it to the inline policy, so it’s something about the role.
I attached the managed policy SecretsManagerReadWrite to the role, and that did work, in the sense I that could now read both secrets from that role.
However, that is more power than I was comfortable giving to the role, so I removed the attached policy and reverted the inline policy, reverting to status quo ante.
And now, despite the fact everything should be exactly as it was two hours ago, everything now works correctly.  The role can read the secret it is supposed to; it cannot read the new secret.
If I ever meet Jeff Bezos at a party, I shall give him some very scornful looks.

Secret encrypted with KMS? Role missing KMS permissions on the key?

Ah, it's not that given that the error message says "no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action".

@jarmod — I don’t know anything about KMS.  The page for the secret says “Encryption key aws/secretsmanager” and the string “KMS” does not appear.  See my edit for details of how the entities were created.

@jarmod — yes, few things are more frustrating than having the computer tell you “You didn’t do that thing that you just did.”

I swear, if I knew where Jeff Bezos lives, I would let my dog relieve herself on his azalea bushes.
OK, in fairness, part of this is my fault.  Let me summarize what happened:

I created a role with an inline policy allowing it to read a particular secret
From the command line, I assumed that role
From the command line, I tried to read the secret, getting “no permissions”
I added a managed policy to the role allowing it to read any secret
From the command line, I tried to read the secret, which worked
I removed that managed policy from the role
From the command line, I tried to read the secret, which still worked!

At this point, there was a fair amount of language used that was... well, some people might call it “inappropriate” but the problem was, it was excessively appropriate.
So I tried going through the same steps again, and realized I had totally mis-remembered Step 5, which was in fact

From the command line, I tried to read the secret, getting “secret not found”

Secret not found?  It’s right gol-darn there!  When I access it from my main profile, it’s there.
But then I remembered that First Rule of AWS: “It’s probably something about the region.”
So I added the magic words --region us-east-1 to the command line.  That was what actually worked.
Then I (after enough fiddling around to forget about the First Rule again) removed the over-powerful managed permission policy and went to try it again.  And of course, I pulled up the same command line, with the region, and it still worked.  The cloud was the same as it was originally, but my use of it had changed subtly.
Actually, it all worked out for the best.  My actual problem was not with the command line, it was in a Lambda function.  I had misspecified the region — I had copied an example that used Oregon, of all places, without spotting the problem — and I wanted to recreate the problem from the command line.  By sheer chance, I got the wrong region there too.
There is no reason for this problem to be happening.  The region is in the ARN of the secret.
tl;dr: It’s something about the region.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230255/how-to-retrieve-secret-from-cross-region-aws-secret-manager-in-terraform

While technically AWS could solve this I'm sure, inferring the region from the ARN and proxying the request from the 'wrong' region to the 'correct' region, I'm not surprised that they don't do it currently. It would be more complex, higher latency, higher API request cost, arguably not what some customers would want to happen under the covers. That said, a clearer error response would certainly be helpful.

@jarmod — yes, I was thinking mostly of the error message: “Hey dipstick, you have your regions mixed up.  Fix it and stop bothering me.”
